# Is it possible to render single characters in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I know you can render text manually using a CustomPainter with a Canvas calling drawParagraph. But this seems to do a lot of extra layout work that I don't really need. I just want to be able to draw single characters on a given x, y position. Is this possible?

Comment: Here is well explained tutorial as to draw something on screen - https://www.raywenderlich.com/25237210-building-a-drawing-app-in-flutter

Comment: I know how to draw, but I want to draw individual glyphs. From this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58478 it seems it is not yet possible I guess. But if anyone knows of a solution please let me know.